# SSAS 2008 and Excel 2010 misterious

Tags: sql-server, ssas, olap, dimensions

I have MS SQL 2008 R2 Enterprise.
Also I have Microsoft Excel 2010.

I have created a cube wich contains 1 dimensions - number of discount cards and Year-Month-Day

also I have created a cube with a measure 'Amount'

Then I connect to the cube via Excel and I make a column with my dimension 'DiscountCard'.
This dimension contains 55000 members.

BUT ! Once I filter this dimension (for example exclude a discount card #2344 ) I have a miracle thing. I can see only 3844 member (other ones are cut).

What to do I can see all my rest members ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you just select "all" again? I did not understand you very well, maybe some print screens would help

Comment: If I select "All" it becomes everything OK. The issue is only in case of filtering.